# How do I fix an Error when using Run Dev with Vite

Tags: json, npm, vite

```
error when starting dev server:
SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input.
```

My JSON is valid, I've checked it with JSONlint. I also recieve the following messages.

```
error when starting dev server:
SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at hasWorkspacePackageJSON (file:///D:/Projects/url.xyz/AskScienceAI-Development/client/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-0bae2027.js:43842:26)
    at searchForWorkspaceRoot (file:///D:/Projects/url.xyz/AskScienceAI-Development/client/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-0bae2027.js:43870:9)
    at searchForWorkspaceRoot (file:///D:/Projects/url.xyz/AskScienceAI-Development/client/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-0bae2027.js:43876:12)
    at resolveServerOptions (file:///D:/Projects/url.xyz/AskScienceAI-Development/client/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-0bae2027.js:61218:22)
    at resolveConfig (file:///D:/Projects/url.xyz/AskScienceAI-Development/client/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-0bae2027.js:61719:20)
    at async createServer (file:///D:/Projects/url.xyz/AskScienceAI-Development/client/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-0bae2027.js:60884:20)
    at async CAC.<anonymous> (file:///D:/Projects/url.xyz/AskScienceAI-Development/client/node_modules/vite/dist/node/cli.js:729:24)
```

Answer (score 0):

Vite was pointing to a syntax error in the JSON of the parent folder.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).